# How to implement anti csrf token per request with a client-side app and api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, csrf

I have a client side app (written in Angularjs) and an api this client uses. The api uses session cookies for authentication (don't ask why, I can't change it).

I am trying implement a per request csrf token generation. Normally if I had server side html rendering I would generate a csrf token for each form as a hidden input.

What is the best way to do this with a client-side Javascript app? I thought of creating an api end point that generates a csrf token if user is authenticated, fetch that token and submit it with post request. But I am not sure if that would actually be secure. Any thoughts ?

I know there are plenty of arguments about csrf token per request or per session. I am trying to figure out what is the best approach to implement this particular mechanism without causing more vulnerabilities; which is csrf token per request with a client-api setup .

Comment: per-request tokens are bad for caching and back-button behavior. per-session tokens are fine.

Comment: I definitely understand and agree.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution in mind and I am going to answer my own question. Please post your answer if you have a better solution or comment if you think this approach has any potential dangers or flaws.

So, what I think I can do is to create a response filter on api and send a new csrf token as a custom response header for every response for current session.

On the client side I can create a http response interceptor to store this csrf token and a request interceptor to add this token as a custom csrf header to send back to the api.

It is also possible to set it as a cookie on every request (SET-COOKIE headers) and let browser handle this (in Angular if cookie XSRF-TOKEN is set $http service will automatically send it as X-XSRF-TOKEN http header).But this will cause invalid csrf issues if multiple tabs are open.